# Arrange the z-index of the cube faces

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

How to arrange the faces of the cube which is overlapping each other. Here I found a cube that works in IE my problem now is the faces of the cube is transparent so when I put an image to it, its overlapping each other.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the ouput: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYMapx
Here is the css:

```
p {
  font: 700 1.5em trebuchet ms, century gothic, verdana, sans-serif;
}

.cube, .cube * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.cube {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: move;
}

.face {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: -8em;
  width: 16em;
  height: 16em;
  /** backface-visibility: hidden; /**/
}
.face:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
.face:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
}
.face:nth-child(3) {
  background: lime;
}
.face:nth-child(4) {
  background: cyan;
}
.face:nth-child(5) {
  background: blue;
}
.face:nth-child(6) {
  background: magenta;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the `.cube` element:

```
.cube {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: move;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

also uncomment (make available) `backface-visibility:hidden;` for opaque *Faces*.

***[jsBin demo (tested in IE)](http://jsbin.com/kalugu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style

Comment: Cheers its working, but how to work that in IE ? thanks,

Comment: @winresh24 edited (thought you know about `-vendor-prefixes`)

Comment: @winresh24 I've edited my answer! (Will not work in IE8 but you know that already I hope, IE8 does not supports CSS3)

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate your help, one more thing sir IE10 doesn't support it either? doesn't work on my side :( I hope you can still help me I've been stuck here for a days now :(

Comment: @winresh24 you need to uncomment the CSS style `backface-visibility` see this demo in IE: http://jsbin.com/kalugu/1/edit?html,css,js,output